# Java SWT: mouseUp() is not fired when opening a Dialog in mousDown()

Tags: java, swt

My program opens a dialog if a certain string is clicked inside a StyledText. So in the mouseDown() I first want to check what has been clicked and then open a dialog. This works. After closing the dialog the mouseUp() is not called. This leads to selecting the text when moving the cursor, as if the user tries to select a text.
I can reproduce the behavior by performing the following tasks:

- Click on String in StyledText
  -> Dialog Opens
- Close Dialog
- Move Mouse without clicking
  -> Text gets marked as selected

In my use case I don't need mouseUp() to be fired. But having it not fired means the OS assumes that the mouse button is still down and selects text. This may be the correct behavior if a dialog opens and steals the focus. But than there must be a possibility to tell the system, that the mouse button has been released.

```
myStlyedText.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("MouseUp is fired");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        if (certainStringClicked()) {
            openDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
});
```

I can verify that mouseUp() is not called because "MousUp is fired" is not printed on console.

What is the best way to handle this? I already tried to set focus on another widget (setFocus() and forceFocus()), but that didn't help.

I tried to call mouseUp myself:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.type = SWT.MouseUp;
event.button = 1;
MouseEvent mouseUpEvent = new MouseEvent(event);
mouseUp(mouseUpEvent);
```

This leads to the message "MousUp is fired", but the selection problem still exists.

I could move the code into the mouseUp() method, but that's not actually what I want. The dialog should appear immediately. What else can I do?

Comment: Very strange... Can you move your logic into the close dialog event?

Comment: Have you tried to 'consume' the event with `e.doit = false` in the `mouseDown`method? Another workaround could be to open the dialog deferred with `Display::asyncExec` that might give the mouse up event a chance to reach the styled text widget.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann e is a MouseEvent and has no `doit`. Setting `event.doit=false` before instantiating the MouseEvent (MouseUp) had no effect. Using asyncExec was also not the solution. I tried the following:`myStyledText.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
            int returnCode = dialog.open();` ... }

Comment: @navy1978 not sure how to do that. The code replaces part of the StyledText's text with what is entered in the Dialog. I can't do this in the Dialog.

Comment: You can try to write your own dialog: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html

Comment: @navy1978 My dialog is a subclass of org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog. Is that what you mean? Maybe I forgot to override an important method?

Comment: Not that, I was thinking to extends Jface Dialog, but it’s better you create your own dialogue starting from Shell, maybe you have even more control and you can achieve what you want, writing your logic in the close event of the Shell, or the click event of the button, or both as you need...

Comment: sorry, my Dialog is a subclass of jface.dialogs.Dialog. I confused that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `myStlyedText.notifyListeners(SWT.MouseUp, null);` to your code.
It should work.

```
myStlyedText.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("MouseUp is fired");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        if (certainStringClicked()) {
            myStlyedText.notifyListeners( SWT.MouseUp, null );
            openDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: This works and is a clean solution in my eyes. But it's important to put the statement inside the if-block, otherwise selection is disabled at all.

Comment: @Sadik Sorry, i don't understand. Why you can't to put the statement inside the if-block.

Comment: You can, no problem. But you didn't when I wrote this comment. It was just a note for others.

Comment: @Sadik Ouch!)) Yes, you're right, i edited my answer after your comment. So, we are find solution? Or not?

Comment: yes, thank you. I've implemented this solution and it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Sadik Good! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a good solution**. But it may be a workaround for some.

It is possible to add `SWT.MODELESS` to the shell style in the constructor of the Dialog, which extends `jface.dialog.Dialog`.

```
setShellStyle(SWT.MODELESS);
```

MouseUp() get's fired now.

The problem here is that it is possible to open many dialogs by clicking the text although one dialog is already open.